# Quick question about curves and basis

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Hello all I have a quick question because I am trying to understand my notes and I am confused. Can anyone here atleast give me a hint or anything!

Taking note of the fact that the normal vector, tangent vector and binormal vector are unit vectors, and form an orthonormal basis. that is, 
|T|=|N|=|B| and 
$\lt T , B \gt = 0$, $\lt T , N \gt =0, \lt N , B \gt=0 $

So I know I can write, $ N'=\alpha T + \tau B + \gamma N$, but I want to try to eliminate the N because I know it isn't needed. So, I am trying to do this by taking the inner product of both sides and noting that because N is a unit vector, N' is orthogonal to N for all values.

I am not sure which respect I should take the inner product to, N or N'?

ie, should I do $\lt N',N \gt = \lt \alpha T + \tau B + \gamma N, N \gt$ or N' instead?
 (and yes I am referring to standard inner product of $\mathbb R^{3} $
Thanks all!

Comment: You need to show that $\gamma =0$. That will show that $N'$ is orthogonal to $N$, as $\langle N', N \rangle = \gamma$.

Comment: @MarkFantini Hm im not sure I know what you mean, because I already know that N' is orthogonal to N due to the theorem that if a vector has unit length the its derivative is orthogonal for all values

Comment: Then notice that $\langle N', N \rangle = \langle \alpha T + \tau B + \gamma N, N \rangle = \alpha \langle T, N \rangle + \tau \langle B, N \rangle + \gamma \langle N, N \rangle = \gamma = 0$. Thus you have eliminated $N$.